# How can I create and drop a postgres database using Liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

How can I create a postgres database using Liquibase?
I want to execute the following command by Liquibase:

```
create database db_name owner user_name;
```

How can I create and drop a postgres database using Liquibase?
I want to execute the following command by Liquibase:

```
drop database db_name;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Liquibase probably isn't the right tool for that.

Comment: You can't do that because Liquibase cannot change the connection and to use the database you have created you would need to re-connect using a different JDBC URL. If you just want a clean database, look into `drop owned by ..`. That can easily be run using custom SQL

Answer (score 0):

I can create this using

1. create own bat file
2. read liquibase.property file from it
3. create Db
4. run liquibase.jar update

```
echo off
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,2 delims==" %%i IN ('findstr  "url" liquibase.properties') DO set url=%%i
echo  %url%

FOR /f " tokens=3,3 delims=/" %%i IN ("%url%") DO set url2=%%i
echo  %url2%

Echo "Starting Deployment" >> Deploy.log

Echo "Create Database"                                                          
psql.exe -h %1 -p %2 -U %3  -c "create database %url2%" >> Deploy.log


Echo "Call liquibase script"
start liquibase.jar  update>> Deploy.log
Echo "Liquibase Script End"
```